# Symfony 4 Doctrine repository not returning one field value

Tags: caching, doctrine, symfony4

I have a problem with on field in my entity.
In dev, everything works perfectly but in prod one field of the repository is returning null.

```
this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository(Realization:class)
->find($id)
```

entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
*/
private $yardage
```

on prod in var dump:

```
["yardage":"App\Entity\Realization":private]=> NULL
```

on dev in var dump:

```
["yardage":"App\Entity\Realization":private]=> int(111)
```

After bin/console c:c nothing changes.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the database your production and development environments using the same? If not make sure the value of the `yardage` column for your selected entity is not null,  in your production database.

Comment: database is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLOSED

some weird cache I think, after the weekend it works fine ...